# bra-ket usage in RMarkdown with Latex

Tags: latex, r-markdown

Is there a way to get bra-ket notation usage in RMarkdown LaTeX chunks?  More generally, is there a way to use other packages from within RMarkdown LaTeX?  I am looking at using bra-ket notation much like found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214728/braket-notation-in-latex

Comment: Yes, you can use the braket package with rmarkdow. You can load whatever packages you want in your header-includes. Can you make a [mre] to give us something to start with?

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure what the minimal reproducible example is in this case.  I want to render $\bra{\phi}$, and I have the standard bookdown template is the starter file.  So, based on the starter bookdown template, how would I download the`bracket` (or any package) and tell it to use when when parsing the expression above?

Comment: Can you add a short markdown file to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
---
title: "bra-ket"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{braket}

output:
  pdf_document: 
       latex_engine: xelatex
---

$\braket{\alpha|\phi}$
$\braket{Let's|go}$
$\braket{I want\ to|drink}$
```

[image]

**P.S.** If you haven't LaTeX at your PC, install MiKTeX or TinyTex. And choose in settings something like this: "Always install missing packages on-the-fly" .

---

**An addition.**

If you want to use something like "bra-ket" in HTML-markdown - try this.

```
<p> Here is bra-ket in HTML: &#9001; &alpha; | &beta; &#9002; </p>
```

Doesn't look cool, like in LaTeX, but works.

All codes of symbols are [there](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) and more usable [there](https://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html)

Comment: I would not recommend miktex. Most users use texlive, which is thus much better tested and also more actively maintained.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz If I uninstall MiKTeX and install TeXlive - all my packages will be deleted?((((

Comment: Yes, they will. However if you then install a complete texlive, you'll never again have to worry about missing packages. It takes a bit of disk space, but safes so much trouble.

Comment: This is what I was looking for -- thanks!  I have TinyTex, which is what is set up by default in RStudio, I believe.  I only interact with it through R, so I don't know where I'd set up "Always install missing packages on-the-fly"...

Comment: Hmmm... I just tried this in bookdown (but without the `output:` statement, and this threw an error: `$\braket{a|b}$`.  Partial error was: `unexpected "{"`.

Comment: I will confirm, I was able to use your straight example as a Rmd file, so it works.  I'm just trying to figure out how to get this to work in bookdown with html outputs as well as pdf ones.  I'll add: It does work on the pdf rendering of the book, so that is really helpful!  Just not the html version...

Comment: @mpettis It doesn't work in the html-version. Do you want to knit rmarkdown in html?

Comment: @mpettis I added a html-solution for you too. If i helped, you can accept my answer by putting a tick, thanks ;)